# Full height - Web Responsive - Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Someone know how to set, in Twitter Bootstrap, a div to be always in full height (100% of screen height), in all resolutions?

I'll really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically any parent containers of the DIV need to also be 100% -- this includes BODY, HTML, etc.. You can add some CSS following the 'bootstrap.css' to override the Bootstrap CSS like this:

```
html,body{height:100%;}

.container {
    height:100%;
}

.fill{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#990000;
    padding:10px;
    color:#efefef;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/zrBGw/

Comment: In my case (Windows + Chrome) I got a vertical scrollbar, because of the padding: 10px. Using the box-sizing: border-box; fixes the problem (I'm basically changing the box model).